# How to start nginx via different port(other than 80)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Hi I am a newbie on nginx, I tried to set it up on my server(running Ubuntu 4),  which already has apache running.

So after I `apt-get install` it, I tried to start nginx. Then I get the message like this:

```
Starting nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

That makes sense as Apache is using port 80.

Then I tried to modify `nginx.conf`, I reference some articles, so I changed it like so:

```
   server {

        listen       8080;

        location / {
         proxy_pass  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9500;
         proxy_set_header   Host             $host:8080;
         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Via    "nginx";
        }
```

After saving this and try to start nginx again,  I still get the same error as previously.  I cannot really find a related post about this, could any good people shred some light?

**I should post all the content in conf here:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

   server {

        listen       81;

        location / {
         proxy_pass  http://94.143.9.34:9500;
         proxy_set_header   Host             $host:81;
         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Via    "nginx";
        }


    }
}

 mail {
      See sample authentication script at:
      http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
 
      auth_http localhost/auth.php;
      pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
      imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
 
     server {
         listen     localhost:110;
         protocol   pop3;
         proxy      on;
     }
 
     server {
         listen     localhost:143;
         protocol   imap;
         proxy      on;
     }
 }
```

Basically,  I changed nothing except adding the server part.

Comment: Do you have _same_ message. May be port had changed to another? Did you try to run nginx via sudo?

Comment: For centos, this link might help http://serverfault.com/questions/566317/nginx-no-permission-to-bind-port-8090-but-it-binds-to-80-and-8080

Comment: You can refer to this [Using ports other than 80 in NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095466/nginx-not-routing-to-the-net-core-project-with-port-other-than-80)

Comment: You can refer to this [Using ports other than 80 in NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095466/nginx-not-routing-to-the-net-core-project-with-port-other-than-80)

Answer (score 226):

You have to go to the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and if this is the default configuration, then there should be a file by name: `default`.

Edit that file by defining your desired port; in the snippet below, we are serving the Nginx instance on port 81.

```
server {
    listen 81;
}
```

To start the server, run the command line below;

```
sudo service nginx start
```

You may now access your application on port 81 (for localhost, http://localhost:81).

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't have service installed (OS X, usually) you may run:

    `sudo nginx -s reload`

Comment: You might need to restart if nginx is already running `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: I am getting error in chrome when trying with 81 port: "This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" but with 80 works well.

Comment: I did this but when I run `netstat`, still there is something listening on port 80. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Also check default in `/etc/nginx/sites-available directory`

Comment: how do you edit the file? i cant modify it as it keeps saying i don't have permission although i have executed chown

Answer (score 30):

Follow this:
Open your config file

```
vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Change port number on which you are listening;

```
listen       81;
server_name  localhost;
```

Add a rule to iptables

```
 vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables 
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 81 -j ACCEPT
```

Restart IPtables

```
 service iptables restart;
```

Restart the nginx server

```
service nginx restart
```

Access your nginx server files on port 81

Comment: My issue was solved using this method which was almost similar to you.

Comment: FYI: The correct filename for nginx under windows would be conf\nginx.conf

Comment: It does not matter what is the name of the conf file as the whole conf dir is sourced.

Answer (score 23):

You will need to change the configure port of either Apache or Nginx. After you do this you will need to restart the reconfigured servers, using the 'service' command you used.

---

**Apache**

Edit

```
sudo subl /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

and change the 80 on the following line to something different :

```
Listen 80
```

If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also have to change the VirtualHost statement in

```
sudo subl /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

and change the 80 on the following line to something different :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

then restart by :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

**Nginx**

Edit

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

and change the 80 on the following line :

```
listen 80;
```

then restart by :

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are on windows then below port related server settings are present in file ***nginx.conf*** at ***< nginx installation path >/conf*** folder.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
....
```

Change the port number and restart the instance.

Answer (score 4):

If you are experiencing this problem when using Docker be sure to map the correct port numbers.
If you map port 81:80 when running docker (or through docker-compose.yml), your nginx must listen on port 80 *not* 81, because docker does the mapping already.

I spent quite some time on this issue myself, so hope it can be to some help for future googlers.

Answer (score -1):

semanage port -a -t PORT_TYPE -p tcp