# Start a new site on port 80

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I created a sample demo site in ruby on rails and deployed it on the server. Currently I am using phusion passenger as the app server. I can see it by giving address as `abc.net:3000`. But instead of port `3000`, I have to use port `80`. I used the following command to start the app server and the site can be accessed as `abc.net`.

```
rvmsudo rails server -p 80
```

I have to configure phusion passenger with nginx. I did it [this way](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu). But when I tired to access the site, but I got the nginx index page. The nginx was started on port `80`.

How can I use nginx and phusion passenger and start the app on port `80`? I tried to start nginx on port `8080` and passenger on port `80`, but my nginx is not starting on port `8080`.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829402/how-to-start-nginx-via-different-portother-than-80?answertab=votes#tab-top. Also, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-ports-8080

Comment: @RajeshCO I already refered this link.

Comment: So you can see it on 3000 or only on 80? Your question isn't clear. It should be 80. This sounds like a virtual host problem.

Comment: You don't need  `rails server`, that's just for development. And you don't have to "start Passenger", it's embedded in Nginx. Check the tutorial you're referenced step by step against your configuration, you've done something wrong on the way.