# PHP: How to accept HTTP requests on a different port?

Tags: php, http

I'm making a simple endpoint for some API and I would like to know how can I achieve this? So the API user can basically cURL it and send some data but instead of the default port 80, he can change it to something else like port 5000 or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless u plan to build your server in PHP (does not making sense). U will have a server listening on that port. That server will have it's php module, which u will point to the right code. Same way you direct the server listening on port 80 to the right code (you put php files under it's www folder, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set up your server to listen to a port other than 80. The only reason servers are set up to port 80 by default is because that is the standard port for web servers that browsers will look to use. You can set a web server to use whatever port you like (as long as your server software of choice provides it that is, the majority will).

You can find relevant Apache documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html

Or if you're using nginx this question should help you out: [How to start nginx via different port(other than 80)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829402/how-to-start-nginx-via-different-portother-than-80)

Depending on your hosting situation, you may also need some firewall adjustments.