# NGINX reverse proxy change port 80 to 8080

Tags: apache, nginx, varnish, ports

I am trying to install and configure Varnish 3 on Centos 6.6

The problem is Nginx is running as reverse proxy on ports 80 and 8080.
Apache is running on port 7080

I did all the changes in conf files of nginx however it is still listening on ports 80 and 8080 that's why varnish is not working.

How can I change the nginx port from 80 to 8080?

netstat -tulpn gives the following: (the x are the ip address of the server)

tcp  0  0 xx.xxx.xx.xx:80       0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      17048/nginx
tcp  0  0 xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080     0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      17048/nginx

Comment: Can you post the nginx config files nginx.conf and all the config files included/references in it. It is most likely that one of the server block is still using 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default or wherever your listen directive is:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12800469

Then restart server!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid link only answers. Do keep the link, but add enough information in your answer to make it readable on it's own.

Comment: Hi,although all the listen directives are changed from port 80 to 8080, nginx is still holding the port 80 instead of 8080 and at the same time port 8080.