# How to RUN rails project on port 80 instead of 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, server, port

I have developer my first `rails` project and uploaded on server where i run successfully.

Now, my project run on `ip:3000` but i want to RUN it on IP means on `port 80`.

Then how its possible to RUN on it. I have both web server `NGINX and APACHE` so where I have to set it to RUN.

Any one have a experience or idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To run it on port 80, you need to run:

```
rails server -p 80
```

If you like to change default (3000) to 80 then you need to do following: 
config/boot.rb:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'

module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge({Port: 10524})
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the port number using `-p` option.

So, to run your app on port 80, you need to do:

```
bundle exec rails s -p 80
```

Comment: Its ok but I want to setting through nginx or apache server. any idea in it.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829402/how-to-start-nginx-via-different-portother-than-80

Answer (score 1):

For apache, you can use passenger to make this work as you'd like, which will default to port 80 (or 443 for https sites).

You need to first install the Apache 'mod': `[sudo] a2enmod passenger`

Then you need to create a new vhost, so in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled add a file called you domain name e.g. mydomain.com in this file you'll need something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/current/public

    <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/current/public>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

Put your source code into /var/www/mydomain.com/current/ restart apache and away you go.

Not sure why you would have apache AND NginX, the above config is for passenger only (there is a nginx equivalent)