# Changing port number of nginx through chef recipe

Tags: linux, nginx, chef-infra

I need to change the port number of the nginx which is installed on my linux node through chef. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829402/how-to-start-nginx-via-different-portother-than-80) SO question?

Comment: Just read the cookbook [`README`](https://github.com/miketheman/nginx/tree/2.7.x#default) ? And if you have no idea how to change an attribute, read https://learn.chef.io

Answer (score 0):

As @Tensibai mentioned, this is clearly spelled out in the README as `node['nginx']['port']`. You can set node attributes using roles, environments, wrapper cookbooks, or policies.