# GoLang HTTPS API

Tags: api, ssl, go, certificate, backend

I have a server in windows using Plesk.

I have a domain (example.com), also I bought a SSL certificate for this domain.

I just installed successfully and configure the domain and ssl in my server. So now I can join to my web using https://www.example.com or example.com and will be redirect to https://....

Until that everything works fine.

But now I have been developed an API in GoLang which can’t start to listen at 443 port for some reason. (I thought that maybe because is being already used ?) So I changed to 8081 port. Now when I want to make a request to my API I have to use https://www.example.com:8081/api/v1/users for example.

The problem is that some applications show me a error “Certificate invalid” which I think is because the port is not 443.  Is there any way that I can run go in 443?

The code in GO is this: (The crt and key are the ones provided by GoDaddy, is where I bought the SSL)

```
func main() {

router := NewRouter()



handler := cors.AllowAll().Handler(router)

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8081", "tls.crt", "tls.key", handler))
}
```

Comment: You sure they're the same exact ones used by your web server? I had this same problem and it turned out I needed to use an absolute path from the root folder of the Ubuntu system to my Apache cert/key.

Comment: Yes, of course. I mean, is my dedicated server and I have my web and my API there.

Comment: use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to check your certificate, you can check both  https://www.example.com:8081/api/v1/users and  https://www.example.com:443, as some other server is running in your system. after making sure that your certificate is valid, I'd recommend to find the other server, stop and disable it, and move your go app to 433

Comment: For example.com is 'trusted' but for 8081 'Port 8081 is not supported '

Comment: let's try a simple example
https://goplay.space/#gwFPRhwQ9dX
 as you have some extra cors stuff, we have to ensure that it works in general

Comment: The server works. I mean i can make request to example.com:8081/api/v1/some-route and it will work. But for example, I don't desactivate the SSL Verification in postman then this is not going to work.

Comment: Seems like my configuration for some reason is not working properly. The tls.crt and tls.key are the one that the I bought. I mean, is not self-signed certificates.

Comment: the whole point of my example above is to assure validity of your certificate, you should deploy it and check with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/. If you pass the test, then you can go back to your real api and find some other issues

Comment: Yes, it show me a error “Port 8081 is not supported”

Comment: I just used https://www.example.com/api/v1/index and it works and show me a message that have a valid certificate: 'Verified by GoDaddy.com, Inc' So I guess that the configuration of certificates in my golang app are okay

Comment: if you managed to pass the test on port 443 with go server, then, I guess, the case is closed, as you struggled only when you were using 8081

Answer (score 2):

1. Run the whole Golang application behind nginx (reverse proxy):
2. Create a Virtual Host Server Block in Nginx using your domain.
   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04
3. Setup your SSL certs
4. Point that domain to your Golang App

   ```
   server {

       server_name example.com;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_pass_request_headers on;
           proxy_read_timeout 150;
      }

       ssl_certificate /path/to/chainfile/example.com/abcd.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privatekeyfile/example.com/abcd.pem;

       if ($scheme != "https") {
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Nginx can run on windows with IIS and plesk?

Comment: By default IIS must be running on port 80. So, you can use a different port for Nginx. Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829402/how-to-start-nginx-via-different-portother-than-80