# How to expose nginx docker image to port other than 80?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm having the `.Dockerfile` (from the [source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html#Real-World-Example)):

```
# build stage
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Where at the end the application is exposed to port **80**. I'm then having another different `.Dockerfile` and for building both of them I'm using the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  service-name-one:
    image: dockerImageFromAbove
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  service-name-two:
    image: someOtherImage
    ports:
      - "3000:3001"
```

And this is the example that is actually working. But I would need to change the port from `nginx` docker image and instead of port 80 I would need to have port 8081. By simple changing this in both files from above, it's not working and in my research I found that the only working example is when exposing to port 80 from nginx.
I tried replacing the line

```
EXPOSE 8081
```

with

```
RUN -P 80:8081
EXPOSE 8081
```

but seems as -P flag is not supported here. So how can I do such a mapping, before exposing nginx to port 80?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829402/how-to-start-nginx-via-different-portother-than-80), but I can't figure out how to use the answers in my docker files.

I also found [this post](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) (part for environment variables), but also not sure how to integrate it with my docker-compose file.

Comment: Why would you need to change the port number on the Docker side?  What configuration do you hope to get in the end?

Comment: Did you update your nginx configuration file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`? It's probably only listening on port 80.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you need to change the container's port, though. Are you trying to bind to 8081 on the host instead of 8080, or do you want the container on 8081 instead of 80?

Comment: @JoelMagnuson when my VueJS application is listening on port **8081** and when doing a staging deployment (development mode) this is the port which I need to map to. The `.Dockerfile` from above, is for deployment (in production mode) for production. I would like to keep the same `docker-compose.yml` file for both cases of deployment and I don't want to change the internal **8081** port in the application, which is leaving the scenario to change the port in the docker image.

Comment: @DavidMaze please see my comment from above

Answer (score 1):

The second file is not a Dockerfile but a docker-compose.yml, you have to change in the docker-compose.yml the ports and it will be ok.
The option -p "hostport:containerport" expose the port when you use command docker run.
Anyway i suggest you to use the supported and official image before change too much the Image in the dockerfile.

Anyway if you really need 8081 try something like this

```
version: "3"
services:
  service-name-one:
    image: yournginxOrSomethingelse
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8085:8081"
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe *-P* needs to be lower case: *-p* (this is for command-line command, not Dockerfile)  The syntax is:

Dockerfile:

```
....
EXPOSE 80
....
```

Command line:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:80 --name my-service my-service:latest
```