# How to run Nginx on a different port other than 80

Tags: nginx

I cannot run Nginx because port 80 is already listening on a docker-proxy service.

```
tcp6     0     0 :::80          :::*           LISTEN      13110/docker-proxy
```

I would like to run Nginx on port 8800 instead of the default port 80.

As such, I've edited the default file as below;

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

listen 8800 default_server;
listen [::]:8800 default_server;
listen localhost;
```

However, I still cannot get it working as expected even after restart.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Below is the error I get;

> ● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
>       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>       
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-04-26 04:23:14 EDT; 13min ago
>       
> Docs: man:nginx(8)
>       
> Process: 16955 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>         
> Process: 16944 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>        
> Main PID: 80941 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>       
> Apr 26 04:23:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
>       
> Apr 26 04:23:11 ubuntu nginx[16955]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
>       Apr 26 04:23:12 ubuntu nginx[16955]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
>       
> Apr 26 04:23:12 ubuntu nginx[16955]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
>       
> Apr 26 04:23:13 ubuntu nginx[16955]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
>       
> Apr 26 04:23:13 ubuntu nginx[16955]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
>       
> Apr 26 04:23:14 ubuntu nginx[16955]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
>       
> Apr 26 04:23:14 ubuntu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>       
> Apr 26 04:23:14 ubuntu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>       
> Apr 26 04:23:14 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

Comment: How you restarted nginx and what's in the error log?

Comment: I have restarted the service. I have added the error log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start nginx via different port(other than 80)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829402/how-to-start-nginx-via-different-portother-than-80)

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to the */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default*

Edit that file and put (If you are willing to put "8800" as your port for nginx)

```
server { listen 8800; }
```

The start the server

*sudo service nginx start*

or

*sudo service nginx restart* if previously running.

Then access localhost:8800

Add a rule to iptables

```
 vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables 
 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8800 -j ACCEPT
```

Restart IPtables

```
sudo service iptables restart;
```

Comment: I have tried on both sites-enabled and sites-available. None of it worked. Please see my error log. Even though I set up to listen on 8800 nginx trying to run it on 80

Comment: Take a look at ps -ef | grep nginx and you will see the actual conf file. Also check the iptables steps.

Comment: I was able to get it working fine without adding a rule to iptables.  Under what conditions is iptables necessary?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is in the line

```
        listen localhost;
```

The "listen" directive can take a port number, a host,
or both.  I believe in your case this line defaults
the port to 80, which would cause the problems you
are experiencing.

Also, beware if "default" is not the only file
in hosts_available.  Each of these (each server block) will default
to using port 80 unless overridden there.  Just
editing "default" would not be enough in that case.

Answer (score -1):

I found this answer on Server Fault helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/655067/is-it-possible-to-make-nginx-listen-to-different-ports

You can add ports to the one server block to keep things simple:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8000;
    server_name example.org;
    root /var/www/;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. The question clearly shows that port 80 is already in use. @Cris P looks like the correct answer although it's not been accepted.