# How to run the nodejs application on port 443

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, port

I have an SSL certificate installed on my site. I would like the application I use to run on port 443 https.

After entering 'nodejs driver' shows me this error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::443
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1298:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1346:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1434:7)
at loadHistory (/var/www/html/bot/driver.js:2230:10)
at load (/var/www/html/bot/driver.js:2216:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/bot/driver.js:242:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
```

Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1325:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 443
}

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. What is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot run 2 services on the same port. The default port of `tls` is `443`. You can change (see: [tls node](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_localport))

Or you can change the port of your `Node + Express.js` run (see: [express.js listen](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#app.listen))

Or on the `NGINX` server, see: [nginx port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829402/how-to-start-nginx-via-different-portother-than-80)