# 502 Bad Gateway after reloading supervisor

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, supervisord

My Flask web application runs using nginx and gunicorn. I use supervisor to let my application run in the background. I always updated my files using Windows Power Shell and the command SCP. After i moved the new edited files, which are already existing on my Ubuntu server, to the server, i use the command `sudo supervisorctl reload` to restart the flask app to see the changes. But this time the flask app did not start and i only get 502 Bad Gateway. It does not matter how many times i reload the supervisor or restart nginx, i only get the error code 502.

Comment: try to run your flask in local address, It seems that your flask app is not working well

Comment: how do you mean local address? The flask app is running good on my pc. I think that nginx or gunicorn has a issue or maybe a wrong conf file

Comment: I mean 127.0.0.1 or localhost, Do you have privileges to edit or view nginx.conf file? what is your flask app run port?

Comment: My flask app runs on the port 80 for http and runs on 0.0.0.0 that the ip of the ubuntu server can be used to open the website

Comment: your user  privileges  to open port in  any address (0.0.0.0) can be your problem, you also check the your nginx opened  servers port, for more information see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12800469/1513086

Comment: i already set the port to 80
the conf file of nginx
`server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.ashkan-tools.de;

        location /static {
                alias /home/admin/flask/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}`

Comment: what does `supervisorctl status [service name]` say? IIRC `supervisorctl reload` just restarts supervisor, you may need to `supervisorctl restart [service name]` to restart your application.

Comment: I get this out of `sudo supervisorctl status flask` `flask                            FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`

//EDIT:
This is the restart command
`sudo supervisorctl restart flask`
`flask: ERROR (not running)`
`flask: ERROR (spawn error)`

Comment: So that means the issue is not supervisor, your application has an error. You'll need to track down the correct log file that might help. I'd prob look in the supervisor logs first if they're capturing stdout from your app. Without the code from your app, no way to know what the issue is, but likely missing env var or problem connecting to database as these are the most typical errors on startup.

Comment: please edit your question, your question is not about nginx, your question is about why your flask server  is not running (or working) on your ubuntu machine,

Answer (score 1):

The issue was a not installed module and a typing error in a configuration file.